# How to manually bind or specify the print screen key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, hardware, shortcut-keys

For a [non-specific](https://askubuntu.com/q/1449879/847449) keyboard, the mappings aren't quite correct from `gkbd-keyboard-display -g 1`:

[image: keyboard]

How can I manually specify the `print` screen key?

OS:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Comment: Please specify your OS version.

Comment: 22.04 jammy is the OS